# Correct terminology for permalinks, canonical URLs, and SEO words in the URL

Tags: url, standards, terminology

I am working on a site where the term "permalink" refers to the SEO-adaptation of the title of a post. The URL structure is a WordPress-like structure, like:

```
http://example.com/<year>/<month>/<date>/<permalink>/
```

So if the title is "Hello world", this `<permalink>` entity would be `hello-world`.

But I think this is wrong and I would like to change it, because I think the term "permalink" should refer to the entire URL.

1. Am I correct so far?
2. What is then the difference between the terms "permalink" and "canonical URL"? Would this actually be a canonical URL, instead of a permalink?
3. Is there a conventional term for what `hello-world` would be in my case? (or, in my case, what would I have to rename the term "permalink" to)

Comment: Unfortunately, permalink isn't well defined.   WordPress uses it to mean essentially the same thing as "canonical URL".   Drupal uses it to refer to the URL with an ID that will always redirect to the current canonical URL like `/node/39339` instead of `/my-awesome-article`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen the term "slug" used for SEO words in the URL. (For [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL#Slug), just so you know I'm not making this up.)

I'd agree with your view that "permalink" and "canonical URL" are the same thing, and refer to the full non-changing URL.

Comment: We also have a tag about it: [tag:url-slug]